# CodeCeption assertContains fails when array contains UTF-8 characters

Tags: utf-8, phpunit, codeception, assertion

I have an assertion to check a key in an array in my CodeCeption tests. The test calls a REST API and checks the returned response.

I have this command:

```
$I->assertContains("key", $resp);
```

The output is:

```
Step  Assert contains "key",{"key":"0m-5m","price":10000,"text":"۰ تا ۵ دقیقه"}
Fail  Failed asserting that an array contains 'key'.
```

But when I change the command to the following, everything works fine:

```
$I->assertInternalType("string", $resp["key"]);
```

This behavior shows that there is a key named `key` in my `$resp` object.

I supposed that the cause may be the `UTF-8` characters, since I've been using `asserContains` a hundred times before and it works as a charm.

Any idea how to solve the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried another assert method of CodeCeption which worked fine for me.

```
$I->assertArrayHasKey("key", $resp);
```